# SQL Server function to convert Unix time to local datetime

Tags: sql-server, unix-timestamp

I'm looking for an efficient SQL Server function (in my case 2005) to convert a unix time value into a SQL Server datetime, using local time (particularly taking account of summertime adjustments - i.e not just adding 01/01/1970 in seconds)

Comment: Please use "SQL Server" to refer to the product and sql-server in the tag. Avoids confusion with "MySql", and there's no such thing as MSSQL.

Comment: There may be no such product, technically, but it's a very commonly used abreviation and you're swimming against the tide there. A search on Google returns nine and a half million hits, of which the first one is the Microsoft sql server homepage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, @ts, {d '1970-01-01'}) as MSSQLdatetime
```

After you have the date, you can now do dateadd on the date depending on the DST state for the returned date. To check for DST you need some form of function, sample:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_GetDaylightSavingsTimeStart]
(@Year varchar(4))
RETURNS smalldatetime
as
begin
 declare @DTSStartWeek smalldatetime, @DTSEndWeek smalldatetime
 set @DTSStartWeek = '03/01/' + convert(varchar,@Year)
 return case datepart(dw,@DTSStartWeek)
 when 1 then
  dateadd(hour,170,@DTSStartWeek)
 when 2 then
  dateadd(hour,314,@DTSStartWeek)
 when 3 then
  dateadd(hour,290,@DTSStartWeek)
 when 4 then
  dateadd(hour,266,@DTSStartWeek)
 when 5 then
  dateadd(hour,242,@DTSStartWeek)
 when 6 then
  dateadd(hour,218,@DTSStartWeek)
 when 7 then
  dateadd(hour,194,@DTSStartWeek)
 end
end
```

You need a simular function to find when DST ends, take a look at this site for more info:
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1372

Comment: Local time, this doesn;t take account of summertime adjustments

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a sample function that will give you info about DST and when it starts. You can then use a CASE in your SQL statement to add the required hours to the output column.

Answer (score 1):

better?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UnixTimestampToGMTDatetime] 
(@UnixTimestamp bigint)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
       DECLARE @GMTDatetime datetime
       select @GMTDatetime = 
       CASE
       WHEN dateadd(ss, @UnixTimestamp/1000, '1970-01-01') 
       BETWEEN 
           Convert(DATETIME, Convert(VARCHAR(4), Year(dateadd(ss, @UnixTimestamp/1000, '1970-01-01') )) + '-03-' + Convert(VARCHAR(2), (31 - (5 * Year(dateadd(ss, @UnixTimestamp/1000, '1970-01-01') )/4 + 4) % 7)) + ' 01:00:00', 20)
       AND
           Convert(DATETIME, Convert(VARCHAR(4), Year(dateadd(ss, @UnixTimestamp/1000, '1970-01-01') )) + '-10-' + Convert(VARCHAR(2), (31 - (5 * Year(dateadd(ss, @UnixTimestamp/1000, '1970-01-01') )/4 + 1) % 7)) + ' 02:00:00', 20)
       THEN Dateadd(hh, 1, dateadd(ss, @UnixTimestamp/1000, '1970-01-01'))
       ELSE Dateadd(hh, 0, dateadd(ss, @UnixTimestamp/1000, '1970-01-01'))
       END
RETURN @GMTDatetime    
END
```